# How do I disable Centaur Tabs in ispell Choices buffer

Tags: ispell, tabs

I need to disable the Centaur-Tabs in the Choices buffer of ispell/flyspell. In [Centaur Tab's site](https://github.com/ema2159/centaur-tabs#disable-centaur-tabs-in-selected-buffers) it says to add a hook, so I tried this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'ispell-choices-buffer 'centaur-tabs-local-mode)
```

But I still get the tabs, and I can't see the words:

[image]

I'm using Emacs 27.0.91 in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs 26.3 contains an `ispell-update-post-hook` within `ispell-command-loop`; however, that hook runs in the *working* buffer just *after* the `ispell-choices-buffer` is created.  I have never installed and/or used `centaur-tabs`, but it is my understanding (based upon a brief review of that library) that most of the code was copied straight from the original `tabbar.el` written by David Ponce.  As such, `centaur-tabs` almost certainly relies upon the `header-line-format` variable to generate the view of tabs.  Although the following code is untested, perhaps it will suffice to answer the question:

```lisp
(add-hook 'ispell-update-post-hook
  (lambda ()
    (with-current-buffer ispell-choices-buffer
      (setq header-line-format nil))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight improvement to lawlist's answer (which quite did not work for me). One could instead just call `centaur-tabs-local-mode` on the `ispell-choices-buffer` in the `ispell-update-post-hook`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'ispell-update-post-hook
          (lambda ()
            (with-current-buffer ispell-choices-buffer
              (centaur-tabs-local-mode))))
```